# tools to study source code using git history

Tags: git

Are there any recommended tools to study the source code of a git repository?
My aim is to understand how has the code evolved with the incremental addition of new 
features to the code that is in github.

I can click on "history" in github, but I was hoping to find some other git-related tool that would allow me to dig into the code in a bit more history-structured way.

Cheers

Comment: I assume you know about gitk?

Answer (score 0):

Just some idea's:

Firstly clone the repo you want to study, then use something like the following:

```
git log --pretty=%H
```

This will list the hash of each commit, then you can use the hash to get the diff between the the hash and the previous commit:

```
git diff HASH
```

By putting these into a script like this:

```
for HASH in `git log --pretty=%H`
do
    git diff ${HASH} > ${HASH}.diff
done
```

You can study what change was made at each point. Using various `git log -1 --pretty=FORMATSTRING HASHOFCOMMIT"` you can get also sorts of information out of a commit. You can also use commands like `git blame filename` to see the commit and author of each line of a file.

As per Jed's comments, don't forget gitk (works on both Unix and Windows).

Comment: You can get this information much more easily by using `git log -p`.

Comment: @Dan Moulding - Agreed, but Albert said he wanted to study the changes, and while I considered saying use `git log -p` it seems more appropriate to offer some ways to break down the output instead of getting one long stream of data.